# HTTPS: will not display images with #, " , or % in name

Tags: image

I have a website that will display https: images just fine. But, if an image has a special character such as a #,  " , or %  the image will not display. My urls are all relative so as to accommodate both http and https. They all show up perfectly on http. 
Sample URL: /images/misc/1_4-20x3_4"-hex-pl_s.jpg. 
Using an Apache server. Programming using Progress Open Edge.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is written in the Apache's access logs?

Comment: Nothing in the logs. Just a 404 error.

Comment: Could you cite some of the lines for both HTTP and HTTPS please? Are they actually equal?

Comment: 2 line for 2 different images                                              https:website/images/misc/1_4-20x3_4%22-hex-pl_s.jpg     http:website/images/misc/1_4-20x3_4%22-hex-pl_s.jpg     https:website/images/misc/%2310-lock-ext_tooth-pl_s.jpg  http:website/images/misc/%2310-lock-ext_tooth-pl_s.jpg

Answer (score 0):

`#` and `%` are reserved characters in URLs. `#` for anchors and `%` for encoding.

Try replacing `#` with `%23` and `%` with `%25`

Comment: If I view the image info this is what it displays:https://sitename/images/misc/1_4-20x3_4%22-hex-pl_s.jpg. The reserved characters are definitely being replaced. (%22 being the single quote.) But the file is not being found.

Comment: I've tried hosting a file of the same name, it seems to work OK for me http://adamish.com/1_4-20x3_4%22-hex-pl_s.jpg

Comment: That's why I'm so baffled. It should work. Could the server not be decrypting correctly? it will pull other images out of the same folder as long as there are no reserved characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of URI escaping.

When your filename contains #, " or %, e.g. `file#1%2".jpg`, you should use something like

```
<img src="file%231%252%22.jpg">
```

Check this site: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

They even have a (manual) converter there, but you should get the point...